# Can I return JSON and redirect to a page from the same action

Tags: json, struts2

Is it possible to return JSON and at the same time redirect to a page from the same action in Struts2.

Note: I am using Struts2 plugin for JSON

Comment: Why do you need this?

Answer (score 2):

You *could*, but what would be the point?

As soon as the browser got the 302 it would redirect, and your data would be lost.

If you need to return *and do something useful* with the data, redirect in JS after processing the data.

Otherwise reconsider the app flow.

Answer (score 1):

Generally there is one response for one request, this response could be json, jsp or other valid action struts results.

You can return the json result in your jsp, process the json result and finally use javacript in your to make a new request to your action.